# django REST Framework - How to properly unittest a custom parser

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have been googling around for some time now and I still couldn't come up with a single match! I wrote a quite elaborate custom parser to convert the incoming data to match my serializer structure.

I want to unittest this properly to be sure that it remains functional when changing or refactoring my code.

But I don't know how! There are literally no example in the internet and just using it naive like this:

```
def test_me(self):
    parser_class = MyFancyParser()
    parser_class.parse(stream={'id': 27, 'other_data': 117})
```

... is not working because it requires a `stream` and not a data dictionary.

Any ideas on the topic?

Comment: Ok, I could encapsulate the logic within a service method and test this... but is this really the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I went with is encapsulating the logic in a custom service/class and just call the class in the parser.

```
class MyParser(parsers.JSONParser):
    def parse(self, stream, *args, **kwargs):
        raw_data = super().parse(stream, *args, **kwargs)
        pk = args[1]['kwargs']['pk']
        service = MyService()
        return service.parse_incoming_data(raw_data, pk)
```

The benefit is obvious: I can test and structure my code as I please without any regard to DRF specifics.

The "general" test if the parser stil works (for example after updating DRF) is handled implicitly by testing the viewset with the API client.

Answer (score 1):

From the [DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#stream)

> A stream-like object representing the body of the request.

So, the dict `{'id': 27, 'other_data': 117}` must be converted to either `bytes` or `string`

---

**Minimal verifiable example**

```
import io
import json
from django.test import TestCase

from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser


class MyFancyParser(JSONParser):
    pass


class TestJSONParser(TestCase):

    def test_me(self):
        parser_class = MyFancyParser()
        json_str = json.dumps({"id": 27, "other_data": 117})
        stream = io.BytesIO(json_str.encode())
        parsed_data = parser_class.parse(stream=stream)
        self.assertEqual(parsed_data, {'id': 27, 'other_data': 117})
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream is anything that can be read (has a `read` method). So you need to wrap any string with [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module.

Remember to test only your code. Since drf parsers are already tested maybe have a look at [how drf tests test parsers](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/19655edbf782aa1fbdd7f8cd56ff9e0b7786ad3c/tests/test_parsers.py#L25-L36)?

Example

```
class TestFormParser(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.string = "field1=abc&field2=defghijk"

    def test_parse(self):
        """ Make sure the `QueryDict` works OK """
        parser = FormParser()

        stream = io.StringIO(self.string)
        data = parser.parse(stream)

        assert Form(data).is_valid() is True
```